# How to check a group of text edit controllers to see if any of them are null?

Tags: flutter

I'd like to have a function that checks to see if any of the text edit controller fields are null.

I wrote this method below, but I wanted to see if there was a more elegant solution.

```
bool _nullfieldExists(){
  //return a true if any of the textEditController fields are null
  if (_textEditControllerNumberPlayers.text == null ){
    return true;
  }
  else if (_textEditControllerSmallBlind.text == null ){
    return true;
  }
  else if (_textEditControllerBigBlind.text == null ){
    return true;
  }
  else if (_textEditControllerAnte.text == null ){
    return true;
  }
  else if (_textEditControllerMyStack.text == null ){
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }   
}
```

Comment: If you want to have more control about TextFields checkout [Reactive Forms](https://pub.dev/packages/reactive_forms). It is really handy.

Comment: from the package you shared, "Validators.required" seems to be the "thing" I will use ?

Comment: you can use form widget for validating the form